# Product keeps trying to install on every startup after a fail

Tags: windows, windows-xp, windows-registry, windows-installer, windows-services

> Product: Pervasive.SQL V8 Workgroup (v8.6) -- Error 1706.No valid
>   source could be found for product Pervasive.SQL V8 Workgroup (v8.6). 
>   The Windows Installer cannot continue.

I've looked in the startup/services for msconfig and could not find this. I tried to uninstall it but fails because it was never installed. Don't have the disks for this so can't do a reinstall if it ever was installed. Anyway to remove this so it stops coming up on startup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Go to this link](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) and then click on the "Run Now" button located on the screen. It should bring you step by step on how to remove that installer from running at startup.